# How can I access the kernel command line from a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

How can I obtain the kernel command line from a Linux kernel module?

This can be achieved by reading `/proc/cmdline`, but it seems like there must be an easier way to access the command line from a kernel module than to open and read a file.

Comment: You know that /proc/cmdline just tells you the parameters that were passed to the kernel at boot right? You cant actually use it to interact with the kernel or send it commands. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-cmdline

Comment: @charlesw Of course. I'm not at all trying to interact with the kernel with /proc/cmdline. I'm trying to get those parameters, which would normally be done by reading /proc/cmdline, in a Linux kernel module, but there's no straightforward way to do that from a kernel module.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to access the enture kernel command line, or just a few parameters?
You could prefix each salient parameter with your module's name.

```
my_module.my_variable=value
```

Then your kernel module can retrieve it using the **module_param()** macro, as described in [Passing Command Line Arguments to a Module](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html)

Comment: It's a weird situation, I need to print the cmdline to the kernel log. But I could do: `insmod module.ko cmdline=$(cat /proc/cmdline)`

Comment: Still seems like there should be a way to access the cmdline directly, but `saved_command_line` isn't exported.

Comment: *"I need to print the cmdline to the kernel log."* -- Why?  It's already in the log.  It's among the first dozen lines output by the kernel.

Comment: It's weird. I need to print it again with KERN_ERR urgency so it gets shown by a logging program.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, and thus not suitable for *production quality* code but found `kallsyms_lookup_name` can be called to look-up a Kernel variable or function by symbolic name which isn't exported.

[get_mem_areas_from_memmap_params](https://github.com/Chester-Gillon/cmem_gdb_access/blob/master/module/cmem.c#L605) is an example where was modifying a module which allocates physically contiguous memory and used `memmap` options on the Kernel command line to reserve some physical memory. When the module loads it wants to parse the command line to find the `memmap` entries to then use the physical memory which has been reserved, and therefore not used by the Kernel.

E.g. the following code was code was used to obtain access to `saved_command_line` which isn't exported:

```C
    const char **lookup_saved_command_line;

    /* Can't find an exported way of obtaining the Kernel command line, so lookup the saved_command_line variable */
    lookup_saved_command_line = (const char **) kallsyms_lookup_name ("saved_command_line");
    if ((lookup_saved_command_line == NULL) || ((*lookup_saved_command_line) == NULL))
    {
        pr_info(CMEM_DRVNAME " Failed to lookup saved_command_line\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }
```

It is also possible to lookup functions which are not exported and then call them. E.g. the following from the above module looks-up and then calls `parse_args` to parse the command line arguments to avoid having to create parsing code:

```C
    /* Lookup the function to parse arguments, to re-use the parsing code which handles escaping of parameters */
    parse_args_lookup = (void *) kallsyms_lookup_name ("parse_args");
    if ((parse_args_lookup == NULL) || ((*parse_args_lookup) == NULL))
    {
        pr_info(CMEM_DRVNAME " Failed to lookup parse_args\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    
    cmdline = kstrdup (*lookup_saved_command_line, GFP_KERNEL);
    parse_args_lookup("cmem params", cmdline, NULL, 0, 0, 0, NULL, &cmem_boot_param_cb);
    kfree (cmdline);
```

The reason this is a hack is there is no *type safety* since had to copy the *expected* function prototype for the function pointer into the module source file and so their is no compile time check that the function pointer matches that of the Kernel the module is being compiled for. The only run-time check is that the requested symbol can be found by name.